# Fedora Sublime Text 3 beesu exec

Tags: exec, fedora-25

I have problem with start Sublime Text 3 on fedora 25 as root. This is my /usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop

```
 [Desktop Entry]
 Version=1.0
 Type=Application
 Name=Sublime Text
 GenericName=Text Editor
 Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
 Exec=/bin/beesu "/opt/sublime_text3/sublime_text" %F
 Terminal=false
 MimeType=text/plain;
 Icon=/opt/sublime_text3/Icon/16x16/sublime-text.png
 Categories=TextEditor;Development;
 StartupNotify=true
 Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/sublime_text3/Icon/16x16/sublime-text -n
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/sublime_text3/sublime_text --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

When I start the program, ask me to enter my root password. When I enter the password, don't do anything. If I remove `/bin/beesu` the program is work perfectly, but everytime when I want to save file it's ask me to enter root password and this is sucks. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, gksu, gksudo or beesu are not supported on Wayland which is now default to Fedora 25.

Read this, https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F25_bugs#Running_graphical_apps_with_root_privileges_.28e.g._gparted.29_does_not_work_on_Wayland

I just installed Fedora 25 today. And it is my first Fedora installed. I am frustrated.